# Questions about repository pattern with Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created an API that is using EF Core with a repository pattern and I have few questions:

1. Post method receives an email address and verify whether user exists on not.

- If an email address does not exist in the `User` table, get the guest access details from the `AccessManagement` table and save in `Entitlement` table and return the details
- If the entry exists, get the user access details and return them

`IGeneralRepository`:

```
public interface IGenrealRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class , new()
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();

    Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity);

    Task<TEntity[]> AddRangeAsync(TEntity[] entity);

    TEntity Update(TEntity entity);

    Task<int> CompleteAsync();
}
```

General repository:

```
public class GeneralRepository<TEntity> : IGenrealRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
{
    private MyDbContext _myDbContext;

    public GeneralRepository(MyDbContext myDbContext)
    {
        _myDbContext = myDbContext;
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(AddAsync)} entity must not be null");
        }

        try
        {
            await _myDbContext.AddAsync(entity);
            return entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not be saved: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public async Task<TEntity[]> AddRangeAsync(TEntity[] entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(AddRangeAsync)} entity must not be null");
        }

        try
        {
            await _myDbContext.AddRangeAsync(entity);
            return entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not be saved: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public async Task<int> CompleteAsync()
    {
        return await _myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            return _myDbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Couldn't retrieve entities: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public TEntity Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        try
        {
            _myDbContext.Update<TEntity>(entity);
            return entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not be updated: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

`IUserService`:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    Task<User> CreateUser(string emailId);

    Task<int> Complete();
}
```

UserService implementation:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly IAccessManagementRepository _accessManagementRepository;

    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository, IAccessManagementRepository accessManagementRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _accessManagementRepository = accessManagementRepository;
    }

    public async Task<int> Complete()
    {
        return await _userRepository.CompleteAsync();
    }

    public async Task<User> CreateUser(string emailId)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.GetAll()
                        .Where(x => x.EmailId.ToUpper() == emailId.ToUpper())
                        .FirstOrDefault();
        
        if (user == null)
        {
            var entitlements = await _userAccessRepository.GetAll()
                .Where( x => x.Default == true)
                .Select( x => new UserEntitlement() { 
                    Id = x.Id,
                    AccessName = x.AccessName
                }).ToListAsync();

           //saving User and Entitlement 
            user = new User()
            {
                EmailId = emailId,
                UserEntitlements = entitlements
            };

            user = await _userRepository.AddAsync(user);
        }
        else
        {
            // Getting current User Entitlement
            var entitlements = await _userRepository.GetAllUserEntitilements();
            var entitlement = entitlements.Find(x => x.UserId == user.UserId);
            user.UserEntitlements = entitlements;
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

API call:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser([FromBody] User user)
{
    var result = await _userService.CreateUser(user.EmailId);
    await _userService.Complete();

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetUser), new { emailId = result.EmailId }, result);
}
```

Questions:

1. Is my method `UserService.CreateUser()` implementation correct? Any better approach?
2. Is the below code is the best approach to filter?

```
var user = _userRepository.GetAll()
                          .Where(x => x.EmailId.ToUpper() == emailId.ToUpper())
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

3. How to get data from User and Entitlement table at one stretch? Something like below `Include` but can not use include because of an error

```
var user = _userRepository.GetAll()
                          .Where(x => x.EmailId.ToUpper() == emailId.ToUpper())
                          .Include<UserEntitlement>()
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

4. How to do insert to one table and update to another table in a single transaction?

Comment: unless you put SaveChanges that is `CompleteAsync` its not affected. So you can insert and update then `CompleteAsync` at the last will do this in single transaction

Answer (score 0):

Leo,

1. I prefer doing the validation of the email outside the `CreateUser` function
2. This comes with another function where you could add to `IUserService` where you can get the user by email `GetUserByEmail`.

   Doing that you can possibly return a proper error or validation message before invoking the `CreateUser` at the API Call

   For example

   ```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser([FromBody] User user)
    {
         var user = await _userService.GetUserByEmail(user.EmailId);
         // or var userRegistered = await _userService.UserExistsByEmail(user.EmailId) returning a bool

         // user registered?
         if (user)
         {
             // The user already exists, return an error or
             // You could update the UserEntitlements here or you could
             // make an HttpPut where the user is updated do nothing here
         }
         ....
    }
   ```
3. An example

   ```
    var user = _userRepository.GetAll()
                              .Include(x => x.UserEntitlements)
                              .Where(x => x.EmailId.ToUpper() == emailId.ToUpper())
                              .FirstOrDefault();
   ```
4. You can do it using UnitOfWork

   [Repository Pattern and Unit of Work](https://medium.com/@mlbors/using-the-repository-pattern-with-the-entity-framework-fa4679f2139)